# Proving an inequality involving complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I need to establish the inequality,
$$\left\vert\frac{z^n-a^n}{z-a}\right\vert \le \frac{|z|^n-|a|^n}{|z|-|a|}\quad n=1,2,\cdots$$ for the distinct complex numbers z and a with $|z|\ne|a|$.

And if the condition $|z|\gt|a|$ is also added, then it is to be shown that
$$n\left\vert\frac az\right\vert^{n-1}\lt \frac{|z|}{|z|-|a|}\quad n=2,3,\cdots$$

**My solution:** Firstly I start with
$$\left\vert\frac{z^n-a^n}{z-a}\right\vert= |z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}a+z^{n-3}a^2+\cdots+za^{n-2}+a^{n-1}|$$

$$\le |z|^{n-1}+|z|^{n-2}|a|+|z|^{n-3}|a|^2+\cdots+|z||a|^{n-2}+|a|^{n-1}=\frac{|z|^n-|a|^n}{|z|-|a|}$$

but **I couldn't prove the second-half of the problem** however this is what I tried
as $|z|\gt|a| \implies \left|\frac az\right|\lt 1$

Therefore taking out $z^{n}$ in the above proven inequality
$$\large |z|^{n-1}\left\vert\frac{1-\left({a\over z}\right)^n}{1-{\frac az}}\right\vert\le |z|^{n-1}\frac{1-\left|a\over z\right|^n}{1-\left|{a\over z}\right|}$$

$$\implies \large \left\vert\frac{1-\left({a\over z}\right)^n}{1-{\frac az}}\right\vert\le \frac{1-\left|a\over z\right|^n}{1-\left|{a\over z}\right|}$$

but I don't think I am going in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed similarly as in your proof of the first inequality. If $|z| > |a|$ then
$$
n|a|^{n-1} < |z|^{n-1}+|z|^{n-2}|a|+\cdots+|z||a|^{n-2}+|a|^{n-1}=\frac{|z|^n-|a|^n}{|z|-|a|} \le \frac{|z|^n}{|z|-|a|} \, .
$$
Now divide by $|z|^{n-1}$ to get the desired inequality
$$
n\left\vert\frac az\right\vert^{n-1}\lt \frac{|z|}{|z|-|a|} \, .
$$